# HttpClient hangs with concurrent tasks

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have about 1000 requests that I'm making when my application starts. After calling ~200 requests, only ~10 are returned and then my application hangs and no more results are returned.

Here is what my code looks like:

// File1.cs

```
await Task.WhenAll(allUsers.Select(user => Connect(user)));
```

// File2.cs (Called inside the Connect method)

```
var result = await client.PostAsync($"https://url.com", 
                    new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)))
```

The HttpClient is static so it shouldn't be a problem with too many instances.

I've tried solutions such as:

1. Setting ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue
2. Placing await client.PostAsync(...) in a using statement
3. Using .ConfigureAwait(false)
4. Setting a Timeout value
5. TPL Dataflow (ActionBlock) with MaxDegreeOfParallelism set to 2

None of the above solutions have worked and I'm running out of options. Is there any reason why it can't / won't throw an exception or return a value? Is there a possibility of a deadlock with too many concurrent requests? Any suggestions would help. Thanks

Ps. I'm using .Net Core 2.1

Comment: Yeah, you probably don't want to make 1000 requests concurrently. The thread and connection pools are probably filling up. Try doing batches of 5.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. I also updated my question

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those two lines, but you will have to show more code. Seeing your whole `Connect()` method would help. And how is `allUsers` populated (if it's an `IEnumerable`, it could be getting populated as it's enumerated, which would affect how this works)?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those two lines either. I'd suggest commenting out the network calls entirely to see if there is some other flaw in your logic that is deadlocking.

Comment: Try posting a complete working sample.

Comment: Did you try setting MaxConnectionsPerServer in you HttpClientHandler?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the operation in the api has been written as a async method(not just the controller action method) and better to check for proper sql scripts with read uncommitted transaction isolation level and select query with no lock kind of basic concurrent execution implementations(if sql db :) ) hence the api mostly doing some db read and writes